# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named

Tags: ros, catkin, rosrun, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to link against the youbot API driver repository from a catkin package.
First I created a catkin workspace named `lib_youbot_test` including:

```
build       devel    src
```

in `src` there is a package named `node_pkg` including:

```
CMakeLists.text    package.xml       main.cpp
```

The `main.cpp` is a node that uses the APIs and headers of youbot driver. (`youbot_driver` package)

This is the `cmakelists.text`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(node_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS youbot_driver)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})
catkin_package()

add_definitions(-DYOUBOT_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR="${youbot_driver_CONFIG_DIR}")

add_executable(node_pkg
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(node_pkg
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

OPTION(USE_SETCAP "Set permissions to access ethernet interface without sudo" ON)

SET(SUDO_COMMAND gksudo)
IF($ENV{USE_NORMAL_SUDO})
    SET(SUDO_COMMAND sudo)
ENDIF($ENV{USE_NORMAL_SUDO})

IF(USE_SETCAP)
add_custom_command(TARGET node_pkg POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${SUDO_COMMAND} setcap cap_net_raw+ep $<TARGET_FILE:node_pkg>
)    
endif(USE_SETCAP)


install(TARGETS node_pkg
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

and this is `package.xml`:

```
<package>
  <name>node_pkg</name>
  <description>
     node_pkg
  </description>
  <author>ALIREZA</author>
  <maintainer email="x@x.de">x</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <url>https://github.com/youbot/youbot_applications</url>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>youbot_driver</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>

</package>
```

**** When I run catkin_make it gives me no error.
BUT MY PROBLEM IS WHEN I RUN `rosrun node_pkg main` I RECEIVE THIS ERROR:

```
[rosrun]Couldn't find executable named below /home/youbot/lib_youbot_test/src/node_pkg

And this is the output ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:
/home/youbot/lib_youbot_test:/home/youbot/lib_youbot_driver:/home/youbot/ros_stacks:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

I would appreciate it if you help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199276/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-.../) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `add_executable(node_pkg main.cpp)` line in your cmakelists is telling cmake to compile main.cpp into an executable named `node_pkg`. Therefore you should run it as:

```
rosrun node_pkg node_pkg
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-12**:
Thanks, it seems like it is OK. I don't have that error but I have to first try it on a real youbot robot.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-12**:
I tried it on the youbot (ros version: fuerte) but I receives this error:
[rospack]  ERROR: stack/package node_pkg not found!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-12**:
Why are you building and running with different versions of ROS? Fuerte shipped with a pretty broken version of catkin; I'm surprised that your package even compiles against Fuerte.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-12**:
Dear ahendrix,
The youbot's internal computer has fuerte but my laptop has hydro. Since I am new to ROS, I first try my program by Laptop then try to the same package for youbot. For fuerte I use and create-pkg  rosmake commands.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-26**:
@ahendrix, I run the program on the real youbot and it works well. Thanks for you help.